# Unable To Start Menu From Left Edge

Tags: css, menu, html-lists, nav

When I try to use this menu, it looks like there is a large on starting on the left side instead of the Home menu starting immediately at the left edge. I'm using display: inline and a float: left but still can't figure it out. Any tips?

```
            <nav>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>    
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your CSS it is hard to say exactly.  I have a feeling it is a margin or padding automatically applied by your browser.

As a temporary solution try putting:

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

In your CSS file to override any margins/padding set by the browser.

Comment: that did the trick. Once I placed that override, it aligned to the left side. thanks!

Comment: No problem... That is really just a temporary solution.  You should look into implementing normalize.css or a css reset.

Comment: Great! Will do look into that.